# ORA 00936 error while using left outer join + syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, ora-00936

I have two tables: T1 and T2

- T1 has a DATE column: CT1
- T2 has a DATE column: CT2

I want to left outer join T1 and T2 with join condition:

```
trunc(CT1,'Mi')=trunc(CT2,'Mi')(+)
```

When I try to run this SQL, I receive error ORA 00936:missing expression.

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: basically my question is can  (+) operator can be applied to an arbitrary expression...if yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you need to put the `(+)` operator immediately after the column name that it applies to.

```
trunc(CT1,'Mi')=trunc(CT2 (+),'Mi')
```

"The (+) operator can be applied only to a column, not to an arbitrary expression. However, an arbitrary expression can contain one or more columns marked with the (+) operator." (from http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm)

In any case, I would suggest using the ANSI syntax. It's clearer, more functional, and portable.

Comment: +1 for the how-to. I agree that burying the (+) operator inside a function reference is not highly readable ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try using ANSI syntax:

```
T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON TRUNC(CT1,'Mi')=TRUNC(CT2,'Mi')
```

The (+) outer join syntax has some limitations, this could be one of them. Of course, if you change this join, you'll have to change them all - you can't mix the two.